# ¿Cómo otorgar privilegios a usuario 'moodle' en base de datos mysql?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, moodle

**Contexto:**

Desplegé con exito [moodle](https://github.com/moodle/moodle) con el [docker compose](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker) oficial, configurado para base de datos `mysql` y la última versión de moodle en github.

Archivo docker compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
  webserver:
    environment:
      MOODLE_DOCKER_DBTYPE: mysqli
      MOODLE_DOCKER_DBCOLLATION: utf8mb4_bin
  db:
    image: mysql:5
    command: >
                --character-set-server=utf8mb4
                --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin
                --innodb_file_format=barracuda
                --innodb_file_per_table=On
                --innodb_large_prefix=On
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "m@0dl3ing"
      MYSQL_USER: moodle
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "m@0dl3ing"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: moodle
```

Configuración y despligue de contenedor:

```sh
# configuración de variables de entorno usando git-bash.
export MOODLE_DOCKER_WWWROOT=/c/moodle
export MOODLE_DOCKER_DB=mysql
cp config.docker-template.php $MOODLE_DOCKER_WWWROOT/config.php

# Ejecutar contenedores en segundo plano y dejarlos corriendo
bin/moodle-docker-compose up -d

# Abrir para testeo manual:
bin/moodle-docker-compose exec webserver php admin/cli/install_database.php --agree-license --fullname="Docker moodle" --shortname="docker_moodle" --adminpass="test" --adminemail="admin@example.com"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pregunta:**

Estoy tratando de otorgarle privilegios al usuario moodle (con el fin de poder ejecutar algunos comandos que requieren privilegios elevados) con el comando:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'moodle';
```

Pero obtengo el error:

```sql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'moodle'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

**Nota**: estoy utilizando docker desktop sobre windows con WSL 2 habilitado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ejecutar el comando se debe ingresar como root con:

```sh
docker exec -it moodle-docker_db_1 mysql -u root -pm@0dl3ing
```

**Referencia:**

- https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/577